# Add an xml feed to Marketo email

Tags: xml, marketo

Any Marketo email developers out there who can help me figure out how to add an XML feed to a Marketo email?

I want to add the feed from here - http://depts.washington.edu/uweb/s-n/w.xml to a Marketo email template.

I'm new to Marketo. I tried creating a web hook but can't seem to figure out how to access the hook from the template. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've done such project for a customer.
You'll need to use a background server-side script that parses the XML feed and uses the [Create/Update Program Tokens](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/assets/tokens/#create_and_update) API to update your email.